# Imprime 2 veces al utilizar el control de entrada

Tags: java

Estoy empezando con java y me encuentro con el siguiente problema. Al utilizar WHILE para controlar la entrada por teclado, imprime dos veces el `System.out.print` del segundo While.

No entiendo por qué en el primer While no tengo el mismo problema.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Activitat_2_2{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int intentos;
        final int numAleatorio = (int)(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        int nombre;
        
        
        System.out.print("BENVINGUT AL JOC: ENDEVINA EL NÙMERO SECRET\n----------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        System.out.print("De cuants intents vols disposar? ");
        while(!input.hasNextInt() || (intentos = input.nextInt()) > 10 || intentos < 1){
        
        System.out.print("ERROR\nIntrodueix un valor numeric entre 1 y 10: ");
        input.nextLine();
        
        }
        
        for(int i = 1; i <= intentos; i++){
        System.out.print("Intent " + i + " ");
        
        while(!input.hasNextInt() || (nombre = input.nextInt()) < 0){
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Error");
            input.nextLine();
        }
        }
    }
}
```